# ZF2 how to rename name of field with join

Tags: mysql, join, zend-framework2

Because my join includes a field named 'id' as well, I need to rename this field name during my sql so it won't override my id field name from the first selected tabel.

My query look likes as follow;

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$select->from('websites');
$select->join(array('s' => 'websites_statistics'), 's.website_id = websites.id');
$select->where(array('websites.website' => $website));
$select->order('s.timestamp DESC')->limit(1);

$rowset = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
$row = $rowset->current();

return $row;
```

So, 's' 'id' field should be renamed to something like 'stat_id'.

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$select->from('websites');
       ->join(array('s' => 'websites_statistics'), 's.website_id = websites.id',
           array('stat_id' => 's.id')); // <-- here is the alias
       ->where(array('websites.website' => $website));
       ->order('s.timestamp DESC')
       ->limit(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay and answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select();
    $select->from(array('p' => 'sub_categories'), array('subcategory_id'=>'p.subcategory_id','subname'=>'p.name'))
    ->join(array('pa' => 'categories'), 'pa.category_id = p.category_id', array('catname'=>'pa.name'));
    $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

### ***

Answer (score 0):

And also we can use this method

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;

->join(array('s' => 'websites_statistics'), 's.website_id = websites.id',
       array('stat_id' => new Expression('s.id'))); // <-- here is the alias
```

This is best method If you have to use Mysql 'AS' on zf2

```
example : array('Month' => new Expression('DATE_FORMAT(`salesInvoiceIssuedDate`, "%m")'))
```